# How to index class type of a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap?

Tags: java, reflection, collections, dictionary

Well... I'm actually implementing a class to convert any object to another using a class called "Adapter". I'm mapping each pair of types SOURCE -> TARGET using a HashMap: HashMap , HashMap < Class< ? >, Adapter > >. Each type have your adapters. For example: String can be converted to Integer, Double and so on. To get an adapter:

```
 Adapter adapter = map.get(String.class).get(Integer.class);
```

I will get the adapters dinamically:

```
 Adapter adapter = map.get(< source_object >.getClass()).get(Integer.class);
```

My problem is that I need put in that HashMap a key to java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap. The Request parameter collection from Servlets is a map. But, when I use .getClass() returns java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap. Is impossible to put a key java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.class on the adapters HashMap :(

Someone can help me?

Comment: I'm implementing a converter to convert all forms entries to objects, the known objects called "ManagedBeans" ;) It's like an JspRuntimeLIbrary but more sofisticated. I need to do this way!

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to make this work in any useful way.  It's _good_ programming practice to hide these sorts of implementation details (like the `UnmodifiableMap` class) from the library user, so you'll always run into these sorts of hidden anonymous classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it help to wrap the UnmodifiableMap in a HashMap?

```
source_object = new HashMap<Object, Object>(source_object);
```

Quite inefficient and not very elegant but maybe a temporary workaround?

Comment: Well... it works! Thanks! As you say, isn't very elegant but solves my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to tmmllr for the help! I based on his propose and improve solution! I put the index to source on HashMap adapters using: java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>()).getClass(). Is more efficient way:

```
 adapters.put(java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap< >()).getClass(),...);
```

Thus I can pass java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap instance and get right adapter! This works \0/

Million thanks to veer for found second solution:

```
 Class.forName("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap");
```

I think this is the most practice way!

Comment: `Class.forName("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap")`

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you should ever use this, though. Just write a generic adapter for all `Map`.

Comment: I just want to do an extensible solution for other programmers make your own adapters with minimum efforts ;)